# Quantlib SWIG python installation failed

Tags: macos, swig, quantlib

I have been trying to install QuantLib and want to use it in Python. However, I am having great trouble building Quantlib-SWIG and hopefully I can get some help here.

I was able to build Quantlib and run all test suite successfully following procedure of http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml (I am on Lion, if it matters). After I download and unzip the Quantlib-SWIG and try to do python setup.py build, I got a lot of errors, all seem to be somewhat repeating of following:

```
QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5640:   instantiated from ‘static int swig::traits_asptr<std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> > >::asptr(PyObject*, std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >**) [with T = boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:4663:   instantiated from ‘int swig::asptr(PyObject*, Type**) [with Type = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > >]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:43476:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/boost/assign/assignment_exception.hpp:24: error: ‘boost::assign’ is not a function,

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5558: error:   conflict with ‘template<class SwigPySeq, class Seq> void swig::assign(const SwigPySeq&, Seq*)’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5585: error:   in call to ‘assign’

/opt/local/include/boost/assign/assignment_exception.hpp: In static member function ‘static int swig::traits_asptr_stdseq<Seq, T>::asptr(PyObject*, Seq**) [with Seq = std::vector<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > > > >, T = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > >]’:

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5640:   instantiated from ‘static int swig::traits_asptr<std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> > >::asptr(PyObject*, std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >**) [with T = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > >]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:4663:   instantiated from ‘int swig::asptr(PyObject*, Type**) [with Type = std::vector<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::Quote> > > > >]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:45813:   instantiated from here

/opt/local/include/boost/assign/assignment_exception.hpp:24: error: ‘boost::assign’ is not a function,

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5558: error:   conflict with ‘template<class SwigPySeq, class Seq> void swig::assign(const SwigPySeq&, Seq*)’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5585: error:   in call to ‘assign’
/opt/local/include/boost/assign/assignment_exception.hpp: In static member function ‘static int swig::traits_asptr_stdseq<Seq, T>::asptr(PyObject*, Seq**) [with Seq = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess> > >, T = boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess>]’:

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5640:   instantiated from ‘static int swig::traits_asptr<std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> > >::asptr(PyObject*, std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >**) [with T = boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess>]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:4663:   instantiated from ‘int swig::asptr(PyObject*, Type**) [with Type = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::StochasticProcess> > >]’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:124772:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/boost/assign/assignment_exception.hpp:24: error: ‘boost::assign’ is not a function,

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5558: error:   conflict with ‘template<class SwigPySeq, class Seq> void swig::assign(const SwigPySeq&, Seq*)’

QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp:5585: error:   in call to ‘assign’
```

I tried a couple version of SWIG and Quantlib-SWIG and didn't seem to have any luck. I have tried SWIG 3.0.6 and 3.0.2. Quantlib-SWIG 1.5 and 1.6. My Quantlib version is 1.6 and boost should be latest as I installed from macports.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It seems that you're not the only one with this problem: see https://dev.lsstcorp.org/trac/ticket/1249 for a similar report, unrelated to QuantLib. It's the first time I heard of it, though. May you check what version of Boost you're using? You should find the information inside <boost/version.hpp>.

Comment: #define BOOST_VERSION 105800

Comment: So it's the latest one. Just to exclude it's something on your SWIG installation, can you try the released QuantLib-SWIG 1.6 and use the contained files without running SWIG? Also, what compiler version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be an issue with namespace not being specified. After adding the namespace, it compiled correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember what I exactly did and have already uninstalled it because I went another direction. I want/need to make sure people don't continue to spend time answering something that no longer needs answering. But because there was a workaround solution, even that goes to great lengths for those who query and find this post.